# sum of two closed sets

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Sum of two closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ need not be closed. If one of them is compact, then the sum is closed.
But if I'm given any two closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then how do I check whether it is open o closed? It will be the best if I can draw the picture. But I'm not being able to do that. 
Consider the following problem :
$X = \{(x, y) ∈ \mathbb{R}^2 | x ∈ R, y = 0\}$,
$Y = \{(x, y) ∈ \mathbb{R}^2| xy = 1\}$
Is $X+Y$ closed?

Answer (score 2):

You have $X+Y = \mathbb{R}^2\setminus(\mathbb{R} \times \{0\})$, which is open, and not closed.

To see this, note that if $x\in X, y \in Y$, then $y_2 \neq 0$, hence $x_2+y_2 = y_2 \neq 0$, hence all points $(x,0)$ are 'missing' from $X+Y$.

If $p \in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus(\mathbb{R} \times \{0\})$, then $p_2 \neq 0$. Then $p=(p_1,p_2) = (p_1-{1 \over p_2}, 0) + ({1 \over p_2}, p_2) \in X+Y$.

Answer (score 2):

In the case $X+Y$ is obviously the whole space minus the $X$ axis (open and not closed). Move the hyperbola $Y$ to left and right (sum $(x,0)$) to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Thd complitements of closed sets are open. The intersection of two open sets is open. Then the union of two closed sets is closed.

Comment: True, but irrelevant here.

Comment: Ah. I understood. It's Minkowski sum. Sorry))